# Reputable Sources

Tags: data-source

I am not sure this that is the correct stackexchange but I could not find a more suitable one.

I am writing an essay which consists of comparing two companies (Ford or Volkswagen) and analysing them to see which is a better investment.

I need to find credible sources about these companies, either in write-ups by known figures or news headlines by reputable papers.

Does anyone have any suggestions on any sources I can use? I am not familiar with known reputable business people.

Thanks

Comment: Are you currently a student? Working for a company?

Answer (score 1):

My first port of call would be to read some reports from investment banks'/brokers' research analysts. I admit that's not easy to get hold of though if you're not working in investments. If you are in the industry just speak to your firm's sales reps and get them.

Assuming from your question, though, that you're a student you may nevertheless have access (in your library for instanace) to a bloomberg terminal and you can find a lot there. e.g. VOW GR Equity BRC `<GO>` for VW.

More generally, have a look at some of the blogs and forum websites out there, often they have full PDFs of broker analysts' research reports available "for free". E.g. [FT Alphaville](https://ftalphaville.ft.com/), [Sum Zero](https://sumzero.com/) or even [ZeroHedge](http://www.zerohedge.com/). You'll need to create a login often mind.